# az: 'upgrade' is not in the 'az' command group

Tags: azure, upgrade, azure-cli

I want to upgrade azure cli to 2.26.1 version from 2.0.81 in window subsystem of linux(wsl ubuntu). I am trying to use command `az upgrade` . It is giving following error:

> az: 'upgrade' is not in the 'az' command group. See 'az --help'. If the command is from an extension, please make sure the corresponding extension is installed. To learn more about extensions, please visit https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/azure-cli-extensions-overview

Is there some way to upgrade it in ubuntu?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I got the solution of it. I just reinstall the azure cli through following link.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli-linux?pivots=apt

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately your az cli version is to old to use this feature.

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/update-azure-cli):

> The az upgrade command was added in version 2.11.0 and will not work with versions prior to 2.11.0. Older versions can be updated by reinstalling as described in [Install the Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli).